# ms access 2007 cascading drop down

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am trying to create several cascading drop down boxes (I will be OK once I get one to work and I'm starting with the easiest). I have a main category-Endoscopy with 3 choices and with each choice having a separate table. On my form I have only one box for the main category. Should I have a second one for the sub category?

I followed the answer from another question asked 2 years ago, and did this:

```
Private Sub Endoscopy_1_AfterUpdate()
Dim strRowsource As String
strRowsource = "SELECT Gastroscopy FROM tblEndo_Gastroscopy WHERE CategoryID = "
strRowsource = strRowsource & Me!tblEndoscopy
strRowsource = strRowsource & " ORDER BY Endo_Gastroscopy;"
Me!tblEndo_Gastroscopy.RowSource = strRowsource
End Sub
```

When I do this I get a run time error: 2465 saying that MS Access can't find the field 'tblEndoscopy' referred to in my expression.

I am not a programmer but do have enough understanding to follow directions. Please help.

Comment: What are the names of your dropdown controls?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without looking at your form, but I am betting you want

`Me!Endoscopy_1` instead of `Me!tblEndoscopy`

Comment: That helped. the run time error is the same but the debuger is appearing on line: Me!tblEndo_Gastroscopy.RowSource = strRowsource. Also if I do get this to work, how do I code it for the other two choices?

Comment: I also tried   Me!Endoscopy_1.RowSource    and    Me!tblEndoscopy.Rowsource

Comment: @user1457610 You are asking people to guess. Why not supply the names of the dropdown controls as JohnFx asks?

Comment: You are really going to need to enlist the aid of a programmer. It isn't productive to go through this line by line with you.